# Find a 2D Array inside a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm trying to find a 2d array inside another 2d array

Like this :

```
let board = [
  [ '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '1' ],
  [ '2', '3', '3', '4' ]
]

let toFind = [ [ '1', '1' ], [ '4' ] ]
```

The function must return the first index of the array i'm looking for, here for exemple it will be `[1,2]`

So i made a function to iterate over the board

```
const findIndex = (toFind, board) => {
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] == toFind[0][0]) {
        if (checkMatch(board, toFind, i, j)) {
          console.log("Match Found");
          results.push([i, j]);
          return results;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("Not found");
};
```

And a function to check if the following elements

```
const checkMatch = (board, toFind, row, col) => {
  let match = true;
  for (let i = row; i < toFind.length; i++) {
    for (let j = col; j < toFind[i].length; j++) {
      if (toFind[i - row][j - col] != board[i][j]) {
        match = false;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(match);
  return match;
};
```

But it's not effectiv, the fuction return `[1,0]`, my check function have something wrong and i can't figure out how to handle it.

Comment: Could you explain how the `toFind` relate to the `board` matrix ( 2d array ) ? Are the values in the `toFind` variable coordinates ? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how ot use it.

Comment: Are you looking for contiguous matches? or just inclusion? ie should `toFind([1,1])` match `[1,0,1]`? or only `[1,1,0]`?

Comment: I'm looking for contiguous matches. The variables of toFind in the same order. The same "shape" if i can say so.